# Reader-Writer using openmp

Tags: openmp, fgets

I'm trying to implement reader-writer problem using openmp.. When the writer acquires the lock before input is entered some readers read the buffer. I'm using fgets() to take input from stdin. Ideally the cursor should stop where input is to be entered. Can anyone please explain me what's happening here. The code is as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>
omp_lock_t r;
omp_lock_t w;
char buffer[10];
int rw=0;
int nr,nw;
void start_read(){
    omp_set_lock(&r);
    nr++;
    if(nr==1){
      omp_set_lock(&w);
      printf("Reader acquired lock\n");
    }
    omp_unset_lock(&r);
}
void end_read(){
    omp_set_lock(&r);
    nr--;
    if(nr==0){

       omp_unset_lock(&w);
       printf("Reader released lock\n");
     }
    omp_unset_lock(&r);
}
void writer_part(){
    omp_set_lock(&w);
    printf("\nWriter acquired lock\n");
    printf("thread %d writing contents --\n",omp_get_thread_num());
    printf("change contents of the buffer\n");
    fgets(buffer,10,stdin);
    printf("%s",buffer);
    omp_unset_lock(&w);
    printf("Writer released lock\n");   
}
void reader_part(){
    start_read();
    printf("thread %d Reading contents -- %s",omp_get_thread_num(),buffer);
    printf("\n");
    end_read();
}


int main(){
int i;
omp_set_num_threads(8);
omp_init_lock(&r);
omp_init_lock(&w);
printf("enter the number of writers\n");
scanf("%d",&nw);
printf("enter number of readers\n");
scanf("%d",&nr);
getchar();
printf("initiliaze the buffer\n");
fgets(buffer,10,stdin);
printf("%s",buffer);

#pragma omp parallel for
for(i=0;i<(nr+nw);i++){
    if(i<nw){
    writer_part();  
    }else{
    reader_part();
    }
}
printf("\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

The output is [image]